# If electrons were much more massive, would the Schrodinger equation still work properly to describe its motion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

According to the de Broglie relation, *λ*=*h*/*p*, the wavelength of a particle is inversely proportional to its linear momentum. Massive objects have a large linear momentum as a result of their mass, therefore their wavelength is negligible. If hypothetically, the mass of the electron increased where the wavelength becomes 'negligible', how would that affect the physical properties of a free electron (no forces). I assume you could just solve the Schrodinger equation for a free particle and substitute in the larger mass for *m* for the electron, however, would how would that change the probability density? Would the electron be less probabilistic as a result of the more negligible wavelength?

Answer (score 0):

> According to the de Broglie relation, *λ*=*h*/*p*, the wavelength of a particle is inversely proportional to its linear momentum.

OK.

> Massive objects have a large linear momentum as a result of their mass, therefore their wavelength is negligible.

No, not necessarily. Their momentum also depends on their velocity, since $p=mv$, both mass and velocity are involved in the calculation of momentum.

> If hypothetically, the mass of the electron increased where the wavelength becomes 'negligible', how would that affect the physical properties of a free electron (no forces).

The mass $m$ is just a parameter in the Schrodinger equation, and you can solve the equation for any value $m$ you like.

A free particle in free space that obeys the time-independent Schrödinger equation can be described using a wave function $\psi$ that satisfies:
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2 \nabla^2}{2m}\psi = E\psi\;,
$$
which is solved by:
$$
\psi(\vec x) = Ae^{i\vec k \cdot \vec x}\;,
$$
where
$$
k = \sqrt{2mE}/\hbar\;.
$$

So, for a fixed $E$, increasing the mass increases the momentum.

> I assume you could just solve the Schrodinger equation for a free particle and substitute in the larger mass for *m* for the electron,

Sure. As illustrated above.

> however, would how would that change the probability density? Would the electron be less probabilistic as a result of the more negligible wavelength?

The wavefunction of a free particle in free space is unfortunately not normalizable in the usual way. This means that eigenstates of momentum are not really physical states and if we want to describe a real particle that is actually localized in space we have to use wave packets.

---

If you prefer to look at a free particle "in a box" of length L. The TISE  solutions then become normalizable standing waves, which can be labeled by an integer $n>0$:
$$
\psi_n(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(n\pi x/L)\;,
$$
and where the energy is:
$$
E_n = \frac{\hbar^2k_n^2}{2m} = \frac{\hbar^2n^2\pi^2}{2mL^2}
$$

Note that in this case the free particle solutions "in a box" are not momentum eigenstates, but rather are linear combinations of momentum eigenstates for momenta $p=\pm\hbar n\pi/L $